# ng-model and session storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session-storage

How to bind complex object in session storage and bind them back to ng-model.

I have a simple input with ng-model as below:

```
obj.arr[0].data.health
```

I am trying to store this ng-model as key and its corresponding value in sessionStorage like below, which works perfectly.

```
obj.arr[0].data.health : somevalue
```

The problem is when i re-visit the page again, the ng-model does not get updated with `sessionstorage` value. The `obj.arr[0].data` is empty when i try to put in browser, but the session storage has the value `obj.arr[0].data.health`.

Is it not advised to store `complex ng-model in sessionstorage`? I am guessing the reference i am getting from `sessionstorage` does not match the reference of `ng-model`.

I am using the below code:

https://gist.github.com/Virakal/6123628

Comment: do you use persist directive? can you see the value in local storage in devtools?

Comment: @Maximus: Yes i can see the key and value...

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) with a object model instead